# Jenkins/Hudson JBoss Plugin wait after Startup?

Tags: ant, jboss, jenkins, hudson

I am starting the JBoss server through the Jenkins JBoss plugin. After that I am executing some Selenium tests through Ant target. Some of the first Selenium tests fail due to timeout, I am suspecting that the Ant test target is executed right after the JBoss has started, and the server has not properly finished the startup. Starting the server takes approximately 2 minutes. Is there a way to set a wait time after startup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could just add a `sleep` command in the Ant target. Would look something like this:

```
<sleep milliseconds="10"/>
```

See the doc here: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sleep.html

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar situation and i resolve it by monitoring the server.log. You can find my blog post about this issue. hope this help. =)

[Linux – Wait until a specific pattern is written on log using tail and sed](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2013/10/22/linux-wait-until-a-specific-pattern-is-written-on-log-using-tail-and-sed/)